# Makefile generation wrong? Warning during build

Tags: makefile, autotools

One of my subprojects contains following Makefile.am:

```
## Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in


lib_LTLIBRARIES =  \
        libodbc_lib.la

libodbc_lib_la_SOURCES =  \
        database_odbc.cpp \
        database_odbc.h

libodbc_lib_la_CXXFLAGS = -I../../dbinterface \
        -DUNICODE \
        -DUNIXODBC \
        `odbc_config \
        --include-prefix` 

libodbc_lib_la_LDFLAGS = -L../dbinterface \
        -ldbinterface \
        `odbc_config \
        --libs`
```

which generates following command:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc -I..    -I../../dbinterface -DUNICODE -DUNIXODBC `odbc_config --include-prefix`  -g -O0 -MT libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.Tpo -c -o libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.lo `test -f 'database_odbc.cpp' || echo '/home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc/'`database_odbc.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc -I.. -I../../dbinterface -DUNICODE -DUNIXODBC /usr/include -g -O0 -MT libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.Tpo -c /home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc/database_odbc.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.o
g++: warning: /usr/include: linker input file unused because linking not done
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc -I.. -I../../dbinterface -DUNICODE -DUNIXODBC /usr/include -g -O0 -MT libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.Tpo -c /home/igor/dbhandler/libodbc/database_odbc.cpp -o libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.Tpo .deps/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -I../../dbinterface -DUNICODE -DUNIXODBC `odbc_config --include-prefix`  -g -O0 -L../dbinterface -ldbinterface `odbc_config --libs`   -o libodbc_lib.la -rpath /usr/local/lib libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.lo  
libtool: link: g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/crtbeginS.o  .libs/libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.o   -L../dbinterface -ldbinterface -L/usr/lib64 -lodbc -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../.. -lstdc++ -lm -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o  -g -O0   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libodbc_lib.so.0 -o .libs/libodbc_lib.so.0.0.0
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libodbc_lib.so.0" && ln -s "libodbc_lib.so.0.0.0" "libodbc_lib.so.0")
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libodbc_lib.so" && ln -s "libodbc_lib.so.0.0.0" "libodbc_lib.so")
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libodbc_lib.a  libodbc_lib_la-database_odbc.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libodbc_lib.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libodbc_lib.la" && ln -s "../libodbc_lib.la" "libodbc_lib.la" )
```

My understanding is that I'm getting the `warning` because there is `-c`in the command.

Problem is I don't see this option in the Makefile.am.

So how do I prevent it?

Or this is something different?

Any suggestions on how to fix the warning?

Comment: I think the libraries to link against should be added to `_LIBADD` (or `_LDADD` if you were not using libtool with `_LTLIBRARIES`) instead of `_LDFLAGS`. I would also add the `-I` and `-D` preprocessor arguments to `_CPPFLAGS`, not `_CXXFLAGS`, but that may be just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not the problem.  You *want* the `-c` here because this command line is trying to create an object file.  The warning is because you have some unknown command line argument and the front-end is assuming it's a linker argument.  The error message is really not great in this situation.

Look carefully at the compiler command line:

```
... -DUNICODE -DUNIXODBC /usr/include -g ...
```

Note here you see `/usr/include` with no option: presumably you wanted `-I/usr/include` but without the `-I` the compiler front-end will mistreat this.

This is the output of `odbc_config --include-prefix` which just prints the prefix.  I don't know why you're using this instead of `--cflags` or whatever but if you want to use it you must prefix it with `-I`:

```
-I`odbc_config --include-prefix`
```

Comment: *I'm* not sure why this Autotools-based project is using a build-time command substitution to identify build flags, as opposed to doing that in `configure` and using an output variable to inject the result into the makefile.  But either way, the chosen flags do need to be determined correctly, as this answer addresses.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, that's how the IDE I work with doing it. Sometimes in the future I will probably switch to do that in configure using either `--with-XXX` or `--enable-XXX` syntax. But for now, I'm ok.

Comment: Skip the `--with-*` and `--enable-*` stuff. Use `PKG_CHECK_MODULES([ODBC], [odbc])` in `configure.ac` and then add `$(ODBC_CFLAGS)` and `$(ODBC_LIBS)` to the respective `Makefile.am` variable. Of course, adding `m4_pattern_forbid([PKG_CHECK_MODULES])` just before you use the macro for the first time will catch it when `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` is unavailable.